# Reason for 27 MOhm resistors on Analog Discovery oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, input

I am looking at the schematic diagram of a BNC adapter for Analog Discovery 2 oscilloscope inputs, and I see 27 MOhm resistors R3 and R4 (see the figure).

What is the point of these resistors?

[image: R3 and R4 resistors]

Comment: Can you not think of any reasons?

Comment: To make input impedance closer to 1 MOhm? Or does it have to do with C1 and C2 caps when AC coupling is on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like they want to keep a DC reference when the JP2 is not switched on and all the current goes through the CAP (when the scope is in 'AC mode'), the ADC probably needs a DC reference, or if only the cap was used the signal would float and wouldn't give a good oscilloscope readout.